# linux: what is the difference between these two symbolic link commands

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to create a symbolic link on the server with the command `ln -s`,

Option 1:

`ln -s /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search /home/thejobco/public_html/demo/typo3conf/ext/`

result 1:

`ajax_search -> /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search`

Option 2:

`ln -s /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search/ /home/thejobco/public_html/demo/typo3conf/ext/`

result 2:

`ajax_search -> /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search/`

Question:

I want to know if the above two options are the same, or there is different between them? Option 1 does not have `/`, option 2 has `/`, but both of them work well, so just wonder which is the standard way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A symbolic link is implemented as a file containing the name of the target.

There is a minor difference, as you've seen: one of the symlinks has a trailing `/`, and the other doesn't. You can see the difference in the output of `ls -l`; on a lower level, this shows up as a difference in the path returned by the `readlink()` system call.

But there should be no functional difference between them -- as long as the target is a directory. Either can be used to access the linked directory.

For a target that's not a directory, this:

```
ln -s /etc/motd good_link
ln -s /etc/motd/ bad_link
```

will result in `good_link` being a valid way to access `/etc/motd`, and `bad_link` resulting in a `not a directory` error.

Comment: For paths in general, a trailing slash means that it is a directory, no slash means it may or may not be a directory.  In this case, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @idfah: true, though note that the trailing slash is significant for certain operations (`cp` and `rsync` come to mind).

Comment: @idfah: I've actually worked on systems (SunOS 4, I think) that permitted and ignored a trailing `/` on a file name. For example, `cat /etc/motd/` would print the contents of the file `/etc/motd`. I'm glad modern systems don't do that, but it gave me the habit of appending `/.` to directory names.