# linux: which is the right way to copy folder?

Tags: linux

I want to copy folder `ajax_search`, path: `/home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search/` to be inside this foler:`/home/thejobco/public_html/demo/typo3conf/ext/`, should I run command this way:

`cp -r /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search/ /home/thejobco/public_html/demo/typo3conf/ext/`

or

`cp -r /home/thejobco/public_html/JCCore/ajax_search/ /home/thejobco/public_html/demo/typo3conf/ext`

I am familiar with window, but not unix/linux, I put `/` after `ajax_search`, I know this way  `ajax_search/`, shows `ajax_search` is a folder, but i do not know should i put `/` after `ext` or not? can anyone explain to me which is the right way to copy folder? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux: what is the difference between these two symbolic link commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157884/linux-what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-symbolic-link-commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `cp`, if the destination directory already exists and you do not use a trailing slash on the *source-dir*, [then you are actually putting a copy of *source-dir* inside *dest-dir*](http://kera.name/articles/2012/08/why-caution-is-advised-when-svn-copying-directories/); this can be a problem when you forgot that the destination directory already exists.

**You should include the trailing slash**, to make it obvious to `cp` that you are trying to copy a directory name to a new directory name, and not copy the directory *into* an existing one, if it exists.