# Moving files failed

Tags: linux, perl

I inherited an perl script and trying it now on an Linux.

I have this command,

```
my $c = "$CONFIG_FILE.completed";
        write_log "Moving to Done: $c\n";
        chomp(my $qxout=qx(mv -t $DONE_DIR $c 2>&1));
        logNdie "$PROGNAME: ERROR: Move to Done FAILED($?) for $c (output='$qxout')\n" if $?;
```

where `$DONE_DIR = /pvc/ohdr/topology`

But it fails to recognize the t option

I get

```
ohdr_cucp_sip_fix_04132022.pl: ERROR: Move to Done FAILED(256) for SIP_CUCP_FILES_VNISIPSUCCESS_20220414132902_1.cnfg.completed (output='mv: unrecognized option: t
```

Any solution?

Comment: or avoid running an external command and just do 'rename $c, "$DONE_DIR/$c" or die "rename $c: $!\n"'

Comment: Use `File::Copy` to do the copying. More robust than `rename`

Answer (score 1):

At first while looking at the documentation for mv I didn't see the '-t' option.

It looks like there are different implementations out there for mv. Most of the man pages I found do not mention the -t option.

I found documentation for mv [here](https://tecadmin.net/mv-command-in-linux-with-useful-example/) that mentions the -t option. I found another  [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294291/what-does-t-do-in-mv-command-example-below) that mentions it also.

Since it isn't recognized on your platform you will need to find another solution or find a way to get the correct version of mv.

The -t option is supposed to specify a directory for moving a list of files into. Since you only have the file specified by $c you should be able to change this

```
mv -t $DONE_DIR $c 2>&1
```

to this:

```
mv $c $DONE_DIR 2>&1
```

Edit: Or, as [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) pointed out, since -t protects from copying to a file named $c if the folder is missing, you can add a trailing slash to the destination like this:

```
mv $c $DONE_DIR/ 2>&1
```

I found a longer explanation at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158248/should-i-put-trailing-slash-after-source-and-destination-when-copy-folders).

Comment: If you want the protection afforded by `-t`, you should use `mv $c $DONE_DIR/`. (Note the trailing slash.)